# Copy only unique entries from one table to another MySQL

Tags: mysql, scheduled-tasks

I'm trying to create scheduled auto-updater for MySQL DB. The script I use is shown below. It's idea is to insert only unique products from table wp_posts to table export_copy. But this one inserts nothing.
Please help me to fix the script.

```html
INSERT INTO `export_copy`(`name`, `link`) 
SELECT p.post_title, p.guid 
FROM wp_posts p 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM export_copy, wp_posts
    WHERE export_copy.id=wp_posts.ID)
```

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query will never work!

Since your table's name is "wp_posts" ,it seem you want copy data from wordpress table to your own

you can handle this by php, firt you must fetch data from table and save that to an array, then export array to insert query

```
$link = mysqli_connect(Your_HOST , Your_User , YOUR_Pass, DB_NAME);
$q = "SELECT p.post_title, p.guid FROM wp_posts p WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM export_copy, wp_posts WHERE export_copy.id=wp_posts.ID)";
$result = mysqli_query($link, $q);
$i=0;
while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $a[$i]['name'] = $row['post_title'];
    $a[$i]['link'] = $row['post_title'];
    $i++;
}
$q = '';
foreach($a as $a)
    $q .= "('".$a['name']."','".$a['link']."'),";

$q = substr($q,0, (strlen($q)-1));
$q = "INSERT INTO `export_copy`(`name`, `link`) VALUES " . $q;
$result = mysqli_query($link, $q);
```

Comment: Nonsense. There is no need to select anything first. Indeed it would be potentially counterproductive to do so.

Comment: Dear Strawberry, Using select can reduce nested select in sql, this is only an solution by php, because question is about an wordpress issue, if you have idea about sql solution please share here, thanks

Comment: I'm afraid that there's nothing in your comment that makes any sense. It seems fruitless to continue this conversation

Comment: Oh, you answer with anger, i don't need continue this conversation, that is only a request for your code solution...

Comment: I'm not remotely angry.

Comment: Oh, I even didn't expected that there is no way to copy from wordpress to custom table without PHP... Thanks for advice. So I need to create scheduled task for PHP instead of making it for SQL.